# Which reporting framework or Reporting controls can be used with Mono.net ?List their names?

Tags: .net, mono, reporting

Like we have Crystal Report for MS.NET ,what are the different Cross platform reporting tool available for mono.net , please list out their names and URLs?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need the cross platform support on server or on client? Or do you search a standalone solution, both in one?

If you have already many crystal reports templates then **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear) can be a solution for you. You can use it to read and run your crystal reports templates. I know it is currently only Java. But on a server this should not be a problem.

Our guys are working on a .NET port. It should be available in a few months. Then it should also work on MONO. The large problem with MONO is that it is not completely. This will produce limits for many application. That what you want do on MONO?

Answer (score 0):

We currently use FlexCel.Net for reporting. It's not free, but its very cheap and you get full source code with it. They officially support Mono(except for the WinForms previewer)

Comment: any comments on fyireporting tool?

Comment: It didn't look very end-user friendly and seemed to still be a big work-in-progress... I can't say much more than that though.. we didn't try it very much